# Can the distance ($r$) or angle ($θ$) of the Polar coordinates contain Complex numbers ($a+bi$)?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

1. Is it possible that distance ($r$) or angle ($θ$) contains Imaginary or Complex number?
2. If the answer is yes, how can I convert a number like that (Polar with complex argument) to Rectangular number? 
   For example:
   **$(r,θ) = (5+2i,  3+4i)$** how to convert to **$x+yi$** ? 
    
   Thank you.

Comment: Is $(r,θ) = (5+2i,  3,4i)$ correct? (I made edit...)

Comment: your RHS contains 3 values instead of 2. is the angle theta 3+4i?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed that typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Substitute $i=e^\frac{i\pi}{2}$ and use the [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) rules for $r$, and the [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Complex_trigonometric_definitions) for the angle, along with some of the [trignometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities). This will give you two polar coordinates which then need to be added together and simplified.

Comment: Thanks, JMP!  This has really given me a good direction.  I mark it as an answer. Now  I understand how to calculate a Polar coordinate when the distance (rho) and angle (theta) contain complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the distance of some complex number (x+iy) from the origin is complex, then it follows that either one of x or y is non-real, otherwise r cannot be complex. Thus your complex number cannot be constructed.

Secondly, complex angles do exist, but the notion of a complex argument of a complex number doesn't seem quite right, not in 2D Argand plane at least.

Comment: This is what I thought at first,  but it can be calculated in some calculators.